# PHP show reminders from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cron

I have reminders in my database, all reminders are shown in a HTML table with  the following fields:

> id, name, phone, email, message

Should I use a CRON job with 5 sec to check which reminder needs to be displayed or should I save date in the HTML page and then try to check date with the help of JavaScript? I have no experience creating reminders before.

**Database:**

```
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| ID |      expiry     |     created_at      |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2015-07-9 14:36 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  2 | 2015-07-9 14:38 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  3 | 2015-07-9 14:40 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  4 | 2015-07-9 14:50 | 2015-07-01 11:22:24 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a route with controller>function Select all reminder with expiry date and then check in your sql query if $result > 0
2. then is_show to make 1
3. Refresh ajax request to 15
4. if any reminder then show the reminder

Answer (score 2):

Describe more please.

If you want to load the page and then see the reminders you can select the rows which time is less than current time.

```
SELECT * FROM `reminder_table` WHERE `expiry` < NOW() AND `created_at` > NOW();
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `reminder_table` WHERE `expiry` <= NOW();
```

according to your purpose.

For a realtime updating you can set a countdown code http://countdownjs.org and alert at countdown finished or any other ways.

**EDIT 1:**

You can also use cronjob and websockets together for the updating process.

Comment: do some page refresh with jQuery ajax or use cronjob in the backend to get your work done

Comment: @meh should i use corn job with ajax or  when page load send data as json to htmk and save to current page...

Comment: @hy_sultani , It all can be done by javascript sending all data to javascript and it will alert when it reaches that time. there is no need to use ajax. try a multi countdown and set the times of each countdown on the page. when it reaches the end, another piece of script can be executed.

Comment: sorry this doesnt help :(